# Capture particular details from `ifconfig` using a script

Tags: bash, scripts, ifconfig

Let's say I run the command `ifconfig` for my connected network.

How can make a bash script to use this command and find what comes after `inet` , `netmask` and `broadcast` and print those IP Addresses in a list in the terminal without showing the command `ifconfig`. So when the script runs, it will only output 3 IP Addresses of the selected network.

Comment: Please give an expected input and expected output.

Comment: Instead of using ifconfig, try `ip address show dev` (followed by the target device, or stop after "address" for all of them). Probably not what you're actually after but worth knowing nonetheless. (Be aware that this will use CIDR prefix notation (eg 10.0.0.1/8) rather than address+mask (same example: 10.0.0.1, netmask 255.0.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Here use the following scripts to get the IP addresses related to the `inet`, `netmask`, and `broadcast` lines in the output of the `ifconfig` command. Mind you I am using the `wlp3s0` network interface as an example

to show the inet address simply run the following command on the connected interface i.e. replace the `wlp3s0` with the name of your connected network interface:

**1. inet**

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 | grep -o -e "inet\ addr:\([0-9]\{1,3\}.\)\{3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}" | grep -o -e "\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}"
```

**2. netmask**

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 | grep -o -e "Mask:\([0-9]\{1,3\}.\)\{3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}" | grep -o -e "\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}"
```

**3. broadcast**

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 | grep -o -e "Bcast:\([0-9]\{1,3\}.\)\{3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}" | grep -o -e "\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}"
```

in addition, if you want to output the MAC address of the interface, use the following command:

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 | grep -o -e "HWaddr \([0-9a-f]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[0-9a-f]\{2\}" | grep -o -e "\([0-9a-f]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[0-9a-f]\{2\}"
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but when I type it in (with the right interface) it doesn't output anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the output of the `ifconfig` command? if you show me the output, I can write you a customized version of the script shown above.